# Interfaces and property visibility

Tags: delphi, oop, interface, delphi-7

I have a simple interface

```
  ISomeProperties = interface
  ['{3AD52E4E-5190-4ABE-8AFC-062295E3A352}']
    function GetPort: integer;
    procedure SetPort(const Port: integer);
  end;
```

GetFunction and SetFunction is visible in code complection. But after I add a property like this

```
  ISomeProperties = interface
  ['{3AD52E4E-5190-4ABE-8AFC-062295E3A352}']
    function GetPort: integer;
    procedure SetPort(const Port: integer);
    property Port: integer read GetPort write SetPort;
  end;
```

GetPort and SetPort methods disappear only propert Port is visible - great.

Now I implement an interface

```
  TSomeProperties = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeProperties)
  private
    function GetPort: integer;
    procedure SetPort(const Port: integer);
  end;
```

But the property **Port** is not visible from a class that implements the interface! Is that a desired behaviour or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Declaring a property does not make the methods not visible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, sorry, my mistake. The're not visible in code complection. Is that right or my Delphi fools me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class is not the interface. Properties on interfaces are mere syntactic sugar, exposing the methods GetPort and SetPort for Delphi.

This property is not really something that must or can be implemented (only the accessor methods), so it is not visible in the implementing class, unless you define a property there too. The only things you can implement are methods.

FWIW, the methods do not "disappear" when you define the property. You can still call them. All members of an interface have the same visibility.

Comment: So basically I should just move my property definition to class that implements the interface and forget properties in an interface?

Comment: If you need the property on the interface, you define it there. If you need it on the class, you define it there. You may end up defining it twice, depending on your needs. I seldom bother to define properties on interfaces, but that is a personal preference. I rather use the methods, when using interfaces.